# Using python, how to attach a contact in Whatsapp and send to multiple numbers?

Tags: python-3.x

I am struggling to click over an element. I am not able to click on the contact element from the attach icon in whatsapp chat. i am using url= "web.whatsapp.com". 
Also is there any other option of doing the task?

I get "NoSuchElementException" error when i run the below code. Please help me to select it correctly.

```py
try:
        chat_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@id = 'action-button']").click()
        time.sleep(2)
        element_presence(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="main"]/footer/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]',30)
        msg_box=driver.find_element(By.XPATH , '//*[@id="main"]/footer/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]')
        msg_box.send_keys(message + Keys.ENTER)
        time.sleep(2)
        attach_icon = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@title = 'Attach']").click()

        # issue starts from here...
        contact_icon = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//svg[@id = 'contact-Layer_1']")
        contact_icon.click()
        time.sleep(2)
        search_contact = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@title = 'search']")
        search_contact.click()
        search_contact.send_keys("pravin tcs")
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class = '_1kfc8_2uQfJ']").click()
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@data-icon = 'send-light']").click()

except Exception as e:
        print("Invalid phone no :"+str(phone_no))
```